# Is it easy to draw a simple sine wave?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried to refer to [Draw a sine wave](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429393/draw-sine-waves)

but it is different.

[image]

if I want to have a copy of wave, like below, can I like add on wave more?

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233140/197451

Comment: @jsbibra. thanks. Do you mind if you can provide an answer? I will select yours as answer. The link provided cannot separate both diagram.

Comment: request be more specific with the requirement

Comment: If you have the equation for the function in the second figure, it should be easy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just copied the code from [the link you provided](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429393/draw-sine-waves) and made minor adjustments to get

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
    declare function={f1(\x)=1.2*sin(2.5*deg(\x));
    f2(\x)=0.6*(1.2*sin(2*deg(\x))+1*sin(4*deg(\x))+1.2*sin(6*deg(\x)));
    }]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=T]
   \draw[latex-latex](0,3)  node[above]{Amplitude} |- (8,0) ;
   \draw plot[domain=0:7,variable=\x,samples=51,smooth] ({\x},{f1(\x)});
  \end{scope}
  %
 \begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm,local bounding box=B]
   \draw[latex-latex](0,3)  node[above]{Amplitude} |- (10,0);
   \draw plot[domain=0:9,variable=\x,samples=101,smooth] ({\x},{f2(\x)});
 \end{scope}
 %
 \path foreach \X in {T,B} {(\X.south) node[below] {Time}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are brillant! Thanks. I need few days to figure out.

Answer (score 4):

You can use also [pgfplots package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) to draw your function. Here is an example based on the function provided by *Schrodinger's cat*:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin = 0, xmax = 9,
ymin = -2, ymax = 2.0,
xtick distance = 1,
ytick distance = 0.5,
grid = both,
minor tick num = 1,
major grid style = {lightgray},
minor grid style = {lightgray!25},
width = \textwidth,
height = 0.5\textwidth,
xlabel=Time,
ylabel=Amplitude
]
\addplot[
domain = 0:9,
samples = 200,
smooth,
thick,
orange,
] {0.6*(1.2*sin(2*deg(x))+1*sin(4*deg(x))+1.2*sin(6*deg(x)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

After compiling you will get:

[image]

You can easily modify labels and different parameters of your illustration. You can also change the function by putting new one in the line:

```
\addplot[
    domain = 0:9,
    samples = 200,
    smooth,
    thick,
    orange,
    ] {YOUR FUNCTION};
```

Check this [post](https://latexdraw.com/plot-a-function-and-data-in-latex/) for a detailed description.